# Introductory resources to mathematical properties of "dynamically recalculable" filters in audio/musical equalizers?

Tags: filters, audio, reference-request

Introductory resources to mathematical properties of "dynamically recalculable" filters in audio/musical equalizers?

Particularly, I want to understand

- What mathematical *features* (e.g. monotonicity of coefficients) of filters are suited for real-time modulated filters?
- How to analyze filters for the required features?

But I want to also understand things such as "filter instability" and the ways they are implemented in real-time (does one apply them in buffers or what?)?

---

*Dynamic recalculation*: That the filter's cutoff and resonance can be recalculated on the fly. Or that the parameters can be adjusted while the filter is running. W/o the filter "blowing up" or something else.

Comment: hm, again, it would be easier if you could at least try to narrow down the field of application; reconfigurable filters are a relatively rare need, and a lot of material will deal with reconfigurable filters *for a specific purpose*.  (I feel like I'm really repeating myself, or what I said in the comments of your previous question, sorry)

Comment: aahh this makes a lot more sense, thank you! Now, I'm no expert in audio processing, but there's enough audio experts around here; I think your edit makes it much more likely you'll get an answer :)

Comment: Book: http://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/6/5/129 (source codes: https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/allaboutaudioeq/repository ) . EqualizerAPO project: https://sourceforge.net/p/equalizerapo/discussion/?source=navbar

Comment: @JuhaP Hey I cannot find anything from the book by quickly searching it using terms like: "recalc", "modulat". So I'm not sure where in it does it present something related to the question.

Comment: @mavavilj seriously, that book seems to be a fine resource about how to design parametric equalizers, and how to adjust them. You'll need to work with the things you get when asking such specific questions. You cannot expect the world to have written a text that answers, and only answers, your very specific needs! I'd thank Juha P for giving me such a nice source, and, try to find the things in that book I want to adapt, and maybe follow up with questions on that, rather than demanding that people have texts exactly in the form you want them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But if one has read the book already, then surely they could save me time and point out where to look at.

Comment: @mavavilj you're really delusional about your problem being solvable by reading a single chapter or even paragraph. Read the darn book – you might learn how to solve your problem!

Comment: @MarcusMüller But I believe that I have a reasonable understanding of the other parts, except for this particular part that I'm asking about. I know how to design or apply filters. What I don't understand is how to do "good quality" variation of the parameters in real-time and what considerations it requires.

Comment: I don't really follow: so you know how to build a parametric equalizer, and you know how these are applied? perfect, because then you know how to change the parameters of that equalizer, and how to do an overlapping transition from one equalizer "state" to the next, and wouldn't need any help.

Comment: Hmm... I did add those two source code links which of 1st link is part of the book ...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Except for the part that I'm asking about: "And what's the "suitability" based on in the mathematical formulation of the filter. E.g. some filters have monotonically behaving coefficients, which I read to be a good thing.

But I want to also understand things such as "filter instability" and the ways they are implemented in real-time (does one apply them in buffers or what?)?"

Comment: That is, because not all filters work equally well in such arrangement. Or they may use too much CPU or whatever.

Comment: Those comments would be a *great* enrichment to your question. Really, can you put all you know about the problem you want answers to into your question? I find it kind of obvious that the more you can describe your problem, and that means giving as much context as possible, the better your answers become.

Comment: See the links 31. S. Särkkä and A. Huovilainen (2011). Accurate Discretization of Analog Audio Filters with Application to Parametric Equalizer Design. IEEE Transactions on Audio, Speech, and Language Processing, Volume 19, Issue 8, Pages 2486-2493. https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/#softaudio

Comment: KVR forum is a good resource and place to discuss regarding the smooth transition etc. - http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modulate in time your filter parameters (like cut frequency), you shouldn't use the usual DF1/TDF2 implementations derived from a polynomial fraction in z.
The reason is that they are originally LTI systems (linear time invariant), which is no longer the case now. The state that they have internally, whether an actual state or a function of the past inputs/outputs, is not reliable when the polynomial coefficients change.
Instead, you should use things like TPT schemas (see the Art of VA filter design at https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=350246) that will keep a state that is compatible with parameter changes. Basically, if you map an existing analog system, you model the state of the capacitors and coils and keep them continuous. This *doesn't* happen when using the z transform.